# What font is used in the codec screens in Metal Gear Solid 4?

Tags: metal-gear-solid-4-guns-of-patriots

What's the font used in Metal Gear Solid 4 for both the subtitles and Codec screens?

[image: Metal Gear Solid 4 codec]

Comment: @Brant that's a nice alternative. I'd tried running it through the WhatTheFont machine with no joy, maybe I'll try the forum.

Comment: [GraphicDesign.SE](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com) has a [font identification tag](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/font-identification) - they might be able to help out if you post your question there (or if it gets migrated). Sorry for a non-ideal answer - not enough rep here to comment yet :)

Comment: Your comment should have been added to Brant's answer, and not at your question.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I could find using Identifont was [AG Book BQ](http://www.identifont.com/find?font=ag%20book%20bq&q=Go), but the lower case 'e' and upper case 'C' are wrong.

If you don't get a good answer, you could try asking the [WhatTheFont forum](http://new.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/forum/).

Answer (score 1):

This one is very, very close. 
http://www.mfgg.net/index.php?act=resdb&param=02&c=6&id=23518

Comment: Wii NTLG-Regular (Wii Menu Font)

Answer (score 0):

It seems like [Avenir](http://www.identifont.com/identify?38%20%20%202JS%208J%201JY%201K7%2074%2026RA%2056W%204PW%20PAE%20J4S%205BU%2058D%201LA%202U%20G39%202BR%20DG%2075%20J%201KS%205P%201U6%202E%202L%2030D%204A%204C%2053K%208N%206X4%208B%2019%206X8%201KI%201QY%207G%209Z). At least it matches in everything I noticed. Hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

I remember seeing the name of the font `Helvetica` in the credits of MGS3. I believe they used it for the menus, subtitles, and most other in-game text. It might be what they used in MGS4.

The codec subtitles resemble very much `Helvetica Black` to me.